# On ATU report - How to override the overall STATUS of testcase in coding while run?

Tags: selenium

I wanted to override and control the overall test STATUS in ATUReport. Currently it is making PASS, FAIL or SKIPPED but I wanted to control that through coding in Java for Selenium suite. Please help if anyone worked on this.

Comment: What did you code so far?

Comment: Do you thinks other person clearly understand what you are trying to say?